# How to parse several floats from one single string?

Tags: python, string, list, parsing

I have a list ['     2.5', '    -1.7     5.1', '     0.0    -0.1     3.6'].
I would like to be able to get the value -1.7 for instance, but if I split the string with the separator '.', I only get nonsense (as it should).
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

split by space !
for example :

```
l = [' 2.5', ' -1.7 5.1', ' 0.0 -0.1 3.6']

print(l[1].split(' ')[0])
```

output:

```
-1.7
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `strip` and `split` each element `i` in the list and then cast each of the resulting elements to `float`, i.e.,

```py
values = [' 2.5', ' -1.7 5.1', ' 0.0 -0.1 3.6']

float_values = []

for i in values:
    for j in i.strip().split():
        float_values.append(float(j))

# [2.5, -1.7, 5.1, 0.0, -0.1, 3.6]
print(float_values)
```

or as a list comprehension:

```py
float_values = [float(j) for i in values for j in i.strip().split()]
```